# Mosaic Board - Best Practice to Set Up Variables from Constructor

Tags: javascript, variables, constructor

I have re-formatted this question so its easier to understand:

**Mosaic**:

I am creating a mosaic board that moves around and produces various animations.

When the user sets up the board, they should pass in parameters to the constructor so it can be passed to other functions. Here a new mosaic is made and various paramteeres are defined like colour, id of the canvas and tile size etc...

```
 var grid = new Mosaic("mosaic_canvas", "#000000", 40, 2, 400, ['#FFFFFF', '#5B95D8', '#E66A87']);

 class Mosaic {

      constructor (canvas_id, bg_colour = "#000000", tile_size, tile_border, tile_qty, colours)

 }
```

Now, my question is how am I able to pass all of these parameters around the file with ease?
For example, within the mosaic class, there is a function that creates the grid, and calls the insertTiles function. Is there an easy way to pass the tile_size, tile_border, canvas height and width to these functions (that are outside of the class).
Things like canvas height and width are use a LOT, what is the best practice to pass these around?

```
//Inside of the Mosaic Class
this.createGrid = function() {

    insertTiles();

}

this.createGrid();

//Outside of the Mosaic Class
function insertTiles() {
    var x, y;
    for (let i = 0; i < tile_qty; i++) {
        x = (tile_size + tile_border) * Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas_width / tile_size)),
        y = (tile_size + tile_border) * Math.floor(Math.random() * (canvas_height / tile_size)),
        console.log("fff");
        tiles.push(newTile(x, y, colours));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, it doesn't make sense. There is no point passing those global variables to the constructor of your class, because being global, they are already available to the class. If you must, you could make an instance of your class global instead, make _number_ and _number2_ members by assigning then in the constructor (e.g. `this.number = number`). Note that `obj` in your example, as it is, will just be empty, it won't contain _number_ or _number2_, because you are not using 'this'

Comment: No. Just no. This is not the way to go about this. – *"otherwise I have to use a long list of parameters I make for each function"* – Tackle this issue differently, this is not the solution.

Comment: Are you asking to make your functions in the files become *methods* of the class?

Comment: Assuming we're in a world where globals are necessary for some reason - There's no point in assigning to global variables from inside the class (it could just be done outside the class). But passing globals that already exist, as parameters to the constructor, can make sense for unit testing because they can be mocked more easily.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I would like to use the variables that have been passed into the constructor throughout the whole document, not just the class. If I use this.number = number, things get long winded when passing parameters to functions later on in the class. For example this function appears inside the class, it passed this.number2 to another function, but if I had a lot more parameters things get big:    addNumbers() { runAnotherFunction(this.number2) }

Comment: @AinsClark Yes, you should definitely pass it around. Please show us your whole code so we can suggest a sensible solution (such as e.g. storing the *instance* of the class in a global variable, which would allow you to access its properties from everywhere, without doing weird things in the constructor function code).

Comment: @Bergi thanks for your reply, I have updated the question a lot, hopefully its clearer to understand what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now to answer your actual question:

That's not how Object-Oriented software works.

If you're going to use object-oriented methods (and it seems reasonable for this use case that you should) then that data *belongs* to the object. It seems like you want to be able to use the data passed to an object constructor in other functions in the same module. Those functions should be *methods of the Mosaic class*, or else you should use an entirely different approach.

For the ancillary problem of having too many parameters, it is common practice in dynamic languages like JavaScript to simply pass in a key/value data structure like a JavaScript object:

```
class Mosaic {
    // here we'll use ES 6 destructuring to pull out the properties we
    // care about from the passed-in object
    constructor ({
        canvas_id, 
        bg_colour = "#000000", // default arguments still work
        tile_size, 
        tile_border, 
        tile_qty, 
        colours
    }) {
        this.tiles = []; // tiles should be a property
        this._canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_id);
        this._tile_size = tile_size;
        // etc etc
    }
}

// note that now we're passing in an object with named properties,
// don't need to remember which is where (less error-prone).
var grid = new Mosaic({canvas_id: "mosaic_canvas", tile_size: 40, /* etc */});
```

for your `insertTiles` function just make it a method of the class:

```
// in class Mosaic definition
insertTiles () {
    var x, y;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.tile_qty; i++) {
        x = (this._tile_size + this._tile_border) * Math.floor(Math.random() * (this._canvas_width / this._tile_size)),
        y = (this._tile_size + this._tile_border) * Math.floor(Math.random() * (this._canvas_height / this._tile_size)),
        console.log("fff");
        this.tiles.push(newTile(x, y, this._colours));
    }
}
```

You can make some tweaks to this (tiles doesn't have to be "public" for instance), but generally speaking this is how we do in JS-land.

Comment: Thank you SO much @JaredSmith, you've really helped! Is it best practice to include all methods inside the class? As in, how do you know when you should keep a function inside or outside of a class?

Comment: @AinsClark rule of thumb: if the function has side effects it should be a method of an instance and if not it should be a stand alone function or static class method. I'm glad it helped, please accept my answer (little green checkmark).

Answer (score 0):

> I hope that makes sense

Eh, not really, none of that is anything that anyone should ever actually do, and it seems like you thought process went "maybe I can use X to solve problem Y, but I don't know how to do X in the context of Y so I'll ask on SO about X but make little or no mention of Y".

You really need Z.

This isn't necessarily an answer because it isn't clear what your actual question is, but is way too long for a comment.

To answer your question in the simplest way possible, just make named variables and pass them to the constructor:

```
var number = 1;  // everybody can see me
var number2 = 4; // me too

class Foo {
  constructor (blah, blah2) {
    ...
  }
}

const foo = new Foo(number, number2);
```

Note however that given that it's not entirely clear why there needs to be a class at all, or why if the values have global visibility they need to be parameters to this particular class, or why you don't just make them publicly accessible properties of the instance being constructed.

What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JaredSmith, I have updated the question, I hope its clearer. Ideally I dont want the person creating the class to have global variables; they are just meant to pass the parameters to the constructor and I can manipulate it from there.